# regex read string matcher.matches first string not match properly

Tags: java, regex

Someone help me
i have a file containing following

```
a                       // true
тодорхойгүй гишүүн\n    // false
ямар нэг                // false
нэгэн                   // false
a good deal             // true
нэлээн                  // false
a long face             // true
уруу царай              // false
...
```

My java code

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { 
 // string from file

                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\sa-zA-Z]{1,}");
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strLine);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    System.out.print(true+ "\n");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(false + "\n");
                    }
            }
```

Output

```
false // there is problem this line must true 
false
false
false
true
false
true
false
```

Why first time not match.

```
I inserted blank line into start of file then output

false
true   // this line was false before i insert blank line
false
false
false
true
false
true
false
```

Comment: Just FYI, you could replace all the code in that *while* loop with `System.out.println(strLine.matches("[\\sa-zA-Z]+"));`

Answer (score 2):

It is strange. You might want to try to carefully examine the first couple lines of the file with hexdump:

```
head -2 file | hexdump -C
```

This should tell you exactly what bytes are at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [\sa-zA-Z]+

Comment: This is exactly equivalent to the regex he has. It shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Yes.Java will inform "illegal escape character".I think no problem in regex.

Answer (score 0):

first two line

```
a
тодорхойгүй гишүүн
```

hexdump

```
0000-0010:  ef bb bf 61-0d 0a d1 82-d0 be d0 b4-d0 be d1 80  ...a.... ........
0000-0020:  d1 85 d0 be-d0 b9 d0 b3-d2 af d0 b9-20 d0 b3 d0  ........ ........
0000-0029:  b8 d1 88 d2-af d2 af d0-bd                       ........ .
```

Comment: The first three characters are not ASCII.  Are you sure this is really a simple text file?  How are you creating it?

Comment: Those three bytes are the UTF-8 BOM [*]. Its use is discouraged by the Unicode Consortium, but many editors insert it anyway when they save a file as UTF-8 (Windows Notepad being the most notorious example).  
[*] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Byte-order_mark

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by removing the first three non-ascii codes.

Comment: That's not really a solution, although it may be all you can do.  If you're creating the file, see if you can elect to save it as UTF-8 *without a BOM* (or signature, as some apps call it).